# Tablesorter JS with Tablescroller Widget, column freeze with multiple checkboxes in multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, tablesorter

I am currently working with a project mainly dealing with database and I use *Tablesorter JS Plugin* to populate my table. What I want to achieve is a table with **more than one fixed columns** and have **multiple checkboxes in multiple columns** in the **scrollable section**. I am using *Tablesorter Bootstrap Theme* as the table styling. I followed this JSfiddle [Dynamic checkbox sorting](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4079/) and *Tablesorter Widget Scroller example*.

The problem is, if I enable `scroller_fixedColumns: <size>`, select all checkbox (in `<th>`) is not working [column 4]. And how to make all the select all checkboxes working in multiple columns [column 4, 5, 6, ...] ?

And here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h3z153hw/)

Your help is really appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in [tablesorter issue #977](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/977#issuecomment-125019501) - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h3z153hw/2/)

Relevant code below. Make sure to include the [`parser-input-select.js` file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    resort: false,
    widthFixed: true,
    headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
    widgets: ["uitheme", "filter", "zebra", "scroller"],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_reset: ".reset",
        filter_cssFilter: "form-control",
        scroller_fixedColumns: 3,
    },
    headers: {
        '.action': { sorter: 'checkbox' }
    },
    initialized: function (table) {
        $(table).closest('.tablesorter-scroller').on('change', 'thead th.action input[type=checkbox]', function () {
            var indx,
                $this = $(this),
                checkboxColumn = parseInt( $this.closest('th,td').attr('data-column'), 10 ),
                isChecked = this.checked;
                $cells = $(table)
                    .children('tbody')
                    .children('tr')
                    .children(':nth-child(' + (checkboxColumn + 1) + ')')
                    .find('input'),
                len = $cells.length;
            for ( indx = 0; indx < len; indx++ ) {
                $cells.eq( indx )[0].checked = isChecked;
            }
            $(table).trigger('update');
        });
    }
});
```